# how to print python list variable at .html

Tags: html, flask

This is my `app.py` code with `flask`

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    tasks = Tasks.query.all()
    tasks_len = len(tasks)
    return render_template('pages/placeholder.home.html', **locals())
```

This is my `pages/placeholder.home.html` code

```
<table id = "t">
  <tr>
      <th>Task</th>
      <th>Starts</th>
      <th>Ends</th>
    </tr>
    <tr> <--! add-hoc printing !-->
      <td>{{tasks[0].title}}</td>
      <td>{{tasks[0].datetime_start}}</td>
      <td>{{tasks[0].datetime_end}}</td>
    </tr>
......
```

How can I generate the `html` code as the length of list?

I tired to use `<script></script>` tag, but it turned out that I can't access `tasks` variable inside the script tag. Help me!

Answer (score 0):

HAHA I found the answer myself. Check it out!

```
<table id = "t">
  <tr>
    <th>Task</th>
    <th>Starts</th>
    <th>Ends</th>
  </tr>
    <ul>
        {% for task in tasks %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{task.title}}</td>
                <td>{{task.datetime_start}}</td>
                <td>{{task.datetime_end}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</table>
```